# Packaging jetbrains-toolbox for NixOS

Tags: nixos, jetbrains-toolbox

I am trying to use the [jetbrains-toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) on NixOS.

The download is a single ELF binary. I fixed it using

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /nix/store/2kcrj1ksd2a14bm5sky182fv2xwfhfap-glibc-2.26-131/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
         --set-rpath /nix/store/y76fs08y8wais97jjrcphdw2rcaka1qa-fuse-2.9.7/lib:/nix/store/4csy6xvbrqxkp3mk6ngxp199xkr476lj-glib-2.54.3/lib:/nix/store/r43dk927l97n78rff7hnvsq49f3szkg6-zlib-1.2.11/lib jetbrains-toolbox
```

Now running the binary results in:

```
Cannot open /tmp/.mount_9TUyRi/.DirIcon
```

A bit of debugging gives:

```
$ strace ./jetbrains-toolbox 2>&1|grep mount
mkdir("/tmp/.mount_HJCQAO", 0700)       = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/.mount_HJCQAO", O_RDONLY) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/.mount_HJCQAO/.DirIcon", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "Cannot open /tmp/.mount_HJCQAO/."..., 40Cannot open /tmp/.mount_HJCQAO/.DirIcon
```

Any idea what might be wrong here? (On a "normal" OS it runs just fine.)

Comment: Did you manage to run it somehow?

Comment: I went the pragmatical way and simply installed intellij directly. - But I'm still curious, what exactly is going on above.

Comment: Looks like it's possible to run it with appimage-run now, but seems it's starting, but not working...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an instance of an unresolved [AppImage bug #296](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/296).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it's working, here is a [PR](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/174272) to nixkgs.