# Running jetbrains-toolbox in NixOS

Tags: linux, nixos, jetbrains-toolbox

I want to install [jetbrains-toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) in NixOS. It's useful to track the beta and cannery channels. I've found it asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350957/packaging-jetbrains-toolbox-for-nixos), but I didn't encounter that problem so I decided to ask it again. So by using [NixOS guide](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Packaging/Binaries), after downloading and unpacking using [this](https://gist.github.com/abn/022c5f9eae491687a766f25bd8322fc0), I ran this

```
$ patchelf \
  --set-interpreter /nix/store/9df65igwjmf2wbw0gbrrgair6piqjgmi-glibc-2.31/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
  --set-rpath /nix/store/9df65igwjmf2wbw0gbrrgair6piqjgmi-glibc-2.31/lib:/nix/store/9sfmwj09ij65qnc8dgv8h56gf12b60nn-zlib-1.2.11/lib:/nix/store/dadpj611mynymmljn7s8d97kfsy89dmc-fuse-2.9.9/lib \
  jetbrains-toolbox                                                                                                                                             

$ ./jetbrains-toolbox
/run/user/1000/.mount_jetbraWshcwf/AppRun: line 14: ./glibcversion: No such file or directory
/run/user/1000/.mount_jetbraWshcwf/AppRun: line 14: [: : integer expression expected
/run/user/1000/.mount_jetbraWshcwf/AppRun: line 35: /run/user/1000/.mount_jetbraWshcwf/jetbrains-toolbox: No such file or directory
```

I searched a lot to find out how can I install `glibcversion` with no success! Any idea how can I fix this?

Also creating one is so easy! Create a file named `glibcversion.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("glibc version: %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());
}
```

build it

```
gcc glibcversion.c -o glibcversion
```

but how can I feed it to `jetbrains-toolbox`?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to build jetbrains-toolbox using `appimageTools.wrapType2`. I believe this creates a somewhat traditional environment where everything is correctly located in /usr/bin and so on. This also ensures that installed ides work correctly.

Also note, that the newest version 1.18.7455 doesn't work. But it works with 1.16.6319.

Here is a nix expression. Build it with `nix-build -A jetbrains-toolbox <filename>.nix`

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
let
  name = "jetbrains-toolbox";
  version = "1.16.6319";
    #version = "1.18.7455";
  sha256 = "4e6f333839af8330a09d9d6fdcd6a635c9ca1f0ae239d8f268249dbd095ca880";
in rec {
  jetbrains-toolbox-src = stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "jetbrains-toolbox-src";

    src = fetchurl {
        url = "https://download.jetbrains.com/toolbox/${name}-${version}.tar.gz";
        inherit sha256;
    };

    installPhase = ''
        #mkdir -p $out/bin
        cp jetbrains-toolbox $out
    '';
  };

  jetbrains-toolbox = appimageTools.wrapType2 {
    inherit name;

    src = jetbrains-toolbox-src;

    extraPkgs = pkgs: with pkgs; [
      libcef
    ];

    meta = with stdenv.lib; {
      description = "A toolbox to manage JetBrains products";
      longDescription = ''
      The JetBrains Toolbox lets you install and manage JetBrains Products in muiltiple versions.
      '';
      homepage = "https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/";
      platforms = platforms.all;
    };
  };
}
```

[Here a little gist how to use in a configuration.nix](https://gist.github.com/SrTobi/ee6104514e2f14a0f1eae201654f2012). Might not be the most idiomatic version... but I'm also new to Nixos :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it's possible to run a current version of Toolbox and I just made a PR to nixpgs, so you can see how it works for me here https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/174272